# B Trees and Sparse Index Algorithm in C# and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm, b-tree

## TLDR;

Can you target disk blocks when writing to disk in JavaScript or C#. Does it matter when you have SSDs.

## Problem

I'm creating a BTree implementation in JavaScript and C#.

In reading [this section of wikipedia on btrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Technical_description) it talks about sparse indexes and lowering disk reads.

It appears to me that it is talking about grouping indexes and records into disk blocks to speed up reading them.

## Questions

I have several questions:

1. Can C# or JavaScript (Node) target disk blocks, or is that something you have to calculate in your code? I.e. work out using the partition tables of the HDD to figure out the block size and chunk data accordingly?
2. Does disk block reads matter so much when we have SSDs.

## Follow Up

Obviously in C# you can create `FileStream`s and `BinaryWriter`s or `StreamWriter`s, but they only take `byte[]`, you can't specify anywhere in particular on the disk - and to be honest, I expect much of writing to the disk is handled in the lower levels - like kernel and disk drivers....

Reading with SSDs makes everything soooo much faster, so effectively, as long as the BTree nodes kept a reference to the exact file and byte marker (or something similar) then specifying that in C# would be easy - and lightening quick anyway. It would be a simple `reader.Seek(/** some offset **/)` and then just read in the record.

I wouldn't even know where to begin to try this with Node, it just has its simple `fs.writeFile()` function....

Answer (score 1):

1) High-level languages like C# and JavaScript generally don't come with APIs that specifically operate on blocks, but you don't have to query partition tables or anything to determine a good block size.

Sectors generally hold 512 bytes of data, but the best size for your application is probably bigger than one sector.  The expensive part of reading from disk is (basically) moving the disk head to the track you want and then waiting for the sector you want to spin around on the platter to meet it.

Think of the track of sectors on the spinning disk.  After the head moves to the sector it wants and reads it, the *next* sector on the disk is already right there.  If you want to read that sector right away, then you don't have to do any expensive moving at all.

For this reason, reading few sequential sectors is only a little bit more expensive than reading one sector, and usually you can use that extra data for something.

When your OS needs to cache memory or data on disk, it reads and writes in 4K blocks.  You should consider that a minimum.

When choosing the block size for your B-tree, figure out how many keys you're going to have in each block, and choose the size by trading off the cost of extra reading (relatively cheap) against the cost of having to traverse extra levels because your blocks are too small (relatively expensive).  You should test, but your ideal blocks will very likely be bigger than 4K.

2) With SSDs the tradeoffs are different.  You no longer have to worry about the cost of moving heads and spinning platters, but it's still faster to read sequential sectors.  You should test again.  You'll find that the optimal sector size is smaller.  You still should not go smaller than 4K, though, since your data goes through the OS memory cache, and that will usually use 4K pages anyway.

Comment: Cool , interesting answer. Only thing I would say is that I was talking about C# and JavaScript.. not Java :P

Comment: @CallumLinington  It's true for those languages, too.  I updated the text to reflect that

Comment: Cool, I'm currently stuck figuring out how to split when the upper limit has been reached...

Comment: I write a function `insertIntoBlock(block, height, key, value)`  It calls recursively into the lower level (with height-1), and splits the target block if necessary.  If it splits, it returns the new key+block id to insert into the parent block.  Otherwise it returns null.